# JPEG decoder for .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, jpeg, .net-core

there is currently no "built in" JPEG decoder class for .NET Core since System.Drawing (except for [System.Drawing.Primitives](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Primitives/)) is currently not present as a nuget package.
I do understand that System.Drawing relies on underlying Win32 GDI code which obviously is not present on all platforms.

I did read some posts about possible implementations and there appear to be some alpha-grade JPEG packages on nuget but I haven't been able to find a proper one.

Does anyone know about a simple way of DECODING JPEG pictures on .NET Core for some server side processing? I don't even need resize or other functions, decoding would suffice perfectly.

Help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
-Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp

With a usage like in these samples:

**Sample 1:**

```
// resizing and filter (grayscale)
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("foo.jpg"))
using (FileStream output = File.OpenWrite("bar.jpg"))
{
    Image image = new Image(stream);
    image.Resize(image.Width / 2, image.Height / 2)
         .Grayscale()
         .Save(output);
}
```

**Sample 2: Accessing Pixels**

```
Image image = new Image(400, 400);
using (PixelAccessor<Color, uint> pixels = image.Lock())
{
    pixels[200, 200] = Color.White;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an ImageMagick wrapper for .net which looks like it now supports .Net Core: https://magick.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

I have also found the following which works like a charm and is extremely slim: https://www.nuget.org/packages/BitMiracle.LibJpeg.NET/